# OSX WIFI to WIFI internet sharing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, wifi-configuration, internet-sharing

I have an oculus quest that needs a wifi connection in order to be setup or download/install games. It does so by connecting to facebook servers, as facebook now owns Oculus. My problem: I live in China and access to facebook servers (among many, many...many others...) is blocked by ISPs.

I therefore need to use a VPN when accessing some websites like facebook.

I know I can do internet sharing on my mac, and therefore enjoy the freedom of my VPN connection is i do a ETHERNET-WIFI internet sharing (Ideal for home) or that I could simply install a VPN on my router. Unfortunately I travel a lot and stay often in hotels that ONLY offer WIFI connections.

So, what I would like to do is a WIFI-WIFI internet sharing.

I have purchased an additional USB wifi adapter, and tested it in both sending (connecting to my router for internet access) and receiving (enabled internet sharing on mac and I could find and connect to it through a mobile phone) configurations. Both work fine. However, in the receiving scenario, while I can connect to the USB adapter I don't have an internet connection and lose the primary connection to my router as well. Basically, no more internet access. Everything goes back to normal once I stop internet sharing and disable the USB adapter.

My question: is there a way to perhaps bridge the 2 wifi interfaces and basically have the USB adapter route traffic (received wifi signal from a phone or an oculus quest for example) to the internal wifi, to allow me to enjoy the comfort of sharing my mac VPN internet connection?

Many thx for any help that you could provide on this !